# repeated Freemarker warning message - Rendering tag out of Action scope

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2, struts, freemarker

I have a Struts web application (core V2.5.30) running on Tomcat9 / Ubuntu server. The syslog file is getting numerous instances of error messages similar to the following. There are no directly accessible JSP's in the application, and JSP's are blocked via `web.xml` per advice in the URL mentioned in the message.

> [2022-04-11 13:17:39] [info] [WARN ] 2022-04-11 13:17:39 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-5] FreemarkerTemplateEngine - Rendering tag /template/xhtml/head.ftl out of Action scope, accessing directly JSPs is not recommended! Please read https://struts.apache.org/security/#never-expose-jsp-files-directly

What's causing these messages to appear?

Comment: Don't call JSP directly. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001664/573032) answer how to prevent it.

Comment: I did that already, as indicated in my original message. The warning messages are appearing in the log nevertheless.

Comment: What is the level of the messages in the logger?

Comment: *Something* is directly hitting a JSP page w/ a S2 tag in it; best bet would be to check the server request logs.

Comment: Every JSP is embedded under WEB-INF, without exception. They are referenced only from struts.xml and via JSP include statements. There are no direct requests for any .jsp files in the logs.

Comment: I matched the request log to syslog, and discovered that the messages are being triggered by requests for "/". The welcome file list specifies <welcome-file>
            /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
 </welcome-file>, which is evidently triggering the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something inside `index.jsp` is calling JSP page. It may be an included or forwarded page. With the same request but the page which is called contains struts tags.

Index page is handled by web container itself if you defined it as `<welcome-file>` in the web application descriptor file. So it didn't handle struts2 filter and hence no action Scope was available.

If you want to make it handled by struts2 you should create the action mapping that returns this page as result.

> If you are using Struts tags inside JSP page, either it welcome file listed or not it should be a `dispatcher` result of an action. Welcome file list files could be handled by the web container if you navigate to the folder of your web content hierarchy and there's a welcome file inside it, and there's no action mapped to that URL. In this case you cannot use struts tags inside the welcome file because you are trying to run it without associated filter, or the struts2 filter is already handled another request.
>
> See the examples of [Hello World](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html) application or [Hello World using Struts2](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/hello-world-using-struts2.html) that would show you how to create action configuration that utilize an `index` action or use actionless results using [Convention Hello World](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/) example.

Comment: I did this, based on other advice I found: 1) change the welcome file list to: <welcome-file>Home</welcome-file>; 2) create an empty file named "Home" in the root web directory; 3) create a mapping in struts.xml from "Home" to /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. That provides an action context for index.jsp while still keeping it private.

Comment: These could be found here if you follow the links from the quoted answer. However, neither of them are triggered from the `/` context. Also index page is useless if you can't navigate to the folder containing it. If this answer helped you to find a solution you should mark it as accepted, the checkbox is on the left of the answer.